# Is it possible to create facebook business page on facebook api?

Tags: api, facebook-page

When I researced I was told creating page is not possible with api.But how can pagemodo do that?
Besides is it possible to send page address(actually page id) with signed request to my application with iframe facebook application?When I decoded signed request data I could get user_id but I need page info.